# Date time export data loader

Tags: data-loader, data-export

I'm using the data loader to export accounts.

I put the following condition in the form of the dataloader:

```
Select NAME FROM Account WHERE LastModifiedDate = 2013-06-11T15:54:00Z
```

But i'm not able to get the account that have lastmodifiedDate equals to 2013-06-11 time 15:54 ( these value are showed by an account).

I don't know which of the following parameters is important to have success:

--My user has: 
Time Zone (GMT+02:00) Central European Summer Time (Europe/Paris)

--Dataloader setting: timezone=Europe/Paris

--with a query in the developer console i see this format: 2013-05-31T12:26:35.000+0000

Please can you help me?

Which should be the right date format in the soql query?

Thank you in adavantage.

BR.

Solution:
set data loader option to GMT.
After write date like this format:

```
    Select id,account.owner.id,ownerid, LastModifiedDate FROM Contact WHERE 
LastModifiedDate >2013-06-13T09:30:00+02:00 and LastModifiedDate <2013-06-13T09:31:00+02:00 and LastModifiedById='005b0000000dbXm'
```

Thanks to all for the support!

Answer (score 5):

2013-06-11T15:54:00Z is GMT
The Z at the end signifies Zulu which is UTC or GMT
All times are stored in the database as GMT times and then corrected for display based on the Users Timezone

So you can either convert to GMT and then query 
2013-06-11T13:54:00Z   (GMT = CET - 2?)

Answer (score 2):

You could try resetting the Data Loader Time Zone setting to **GMT**. I don't believe this directly affects the Export SOQL query, but it is worth checking if the expected data isn't coming back with the expected GMT DateTime.

[image: Data Loader Time Zone]

Failing that, try exporting the LastModifiedDate in a DataLoader export SOQL query when selecting the Account by Id. This may reveal why the expected value isn't being returned.